# GameObject hit doesn't return the correct value

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I don't have the source code right now, I will try to explain my error:

I created a multidimensional Array of GameObject, for each GameObject I created a primitive cube, added a script component containing a class with a boolean attribute with relative set/get method, set his attribute to true and moved the transform.

Then in my Update() function I want to get the value of the attribute of the clicked GameObject.

The script is working but I get FALSE instead of TRUE.

For Debug I put a `Destroy(hit.trasform.gameObject)` and the `GameObject` is destroyed, but still log FALSE instead of true.

Is it something wrong with the procedure? I have forgot something?

If isn't clear I will upload the code later when I have access!

Comment: what method you use for accessing that gameObject that you hit

Comment: hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>().getBoolean();

Answer (score 0):

Create a function inside the `Tile`:

```
public void setBoolean(bool b)
{
    yourBool = b;
    Debug.Log("Printing the boolean value: " + yourBool);
}
```

Then in your collision code:

```
hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("setBoolean", true);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>().setBoolean(true);
```